# Getting real size of document with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css

Some websites (like stackoverflow.com here) set `height: 100%` and / or `width: 100%` of the `<html>` and / or `<body>` elements (for some reason, which I don't understand). CSS by default sets `overflow: visible` for all elements in the document (afaik), so child elements which overlaps the boundary of their parent element are not cut off and if they leave the viewport, the browser might show scrollbars. So far, so good.

But if `height: 100%` is set for both elements, `html` and `body`, how to find out the real (full) size of the entire document then? In this case `document.documentElement.getBoundingClientRect()` and `document.body.getBoundingClientRect()` would return only the height *of the visible viewport*.

Try it out: Go to https://stackoverflow.com/ and execute following code in console:

```
var de = document.documentElement;
var b = document.body;

console.log('Before:');
console.log(de.getBoundingClientRect().height);  // or de.offsetHeight
console.log(b.getBoundingClientRect().height);  // or b.offsetHeight

de.style.height = '100%';
b.style.height = '100%';

console.log('After:');
console.log(de.getBoundingClientRect().height);  // or de.offsetHeight
console.log(b.getBoundingClientRect().height);  // or b.offsetHeight
```

In my case, the output is:

```
Before:
638
8352.2333984375
After:
638
638
```

The first "638" is because on stackoverflow.com the `<html>` elements CSS `height` attribute is already set to 100%, like I wrote above. But the vertical scrollbar is still visible and the page can be scrolled down.

So if the height of both elements is set to 100%, which other options do I have to find out the real size of the entire document? `offsetHeight` returns the same values, so it can't be used (it also won't respect any CSS transformations, like skewing). The only way I can think of would be to go through **all** elements in the document, get their absolute (relative to documents boundary) position of the bottom edge and take the highest value. Maybe something like this:

```
(function() {
    var getAbsolutePos = function(elm) {
        var pos = {x: 0, y: 0};

        if (elm.offsetParent) {
            do {
                pos.x += elm.offsetLeft;
                pos.y += elm.offsetTop;
            } while (elm = elm.offsetParent);
        }

        return pos;
    };

    var e = document.querySelectorAll("*");
    var btm, docHeight = 0;
    for (var i=0; i < e.length; ++i)
    {
        btm = getAbsolutePos(e[i]).y + e[i].offsetHeight;
        if (btm > docHeight) {
            docHeight = btm;
        }
    }

    console.log('Page height: ' + docHeight);
})();

// Output: "Page height: 8416"
```

But this looks quite dirty and I guess that this could be resource intensive (depending of elements count), especially when this calculation happens for example in the onMouseMove event. Even worse on mobile devices, where power consumption would raise.

Is there any other more efficient way to find out the full size of the document with pure JavaScript?

Answer (score 1):

Check this article that is about viewport, device, and document size https://www.kirupa.com/html5/viewport_device_document_size.htm.In order to get the real document size it is use document.body.clientWidth and document.body.clientHeight. Itried in https://stackoverflow.com/ and i get the same result that is 8416 right?

Comment: With `clientHeight` I get the same viewport dimensions again. But `scrollHeight` looks good. I think this could be the solution. I have to test it first, but I thank you for your hint! I will get back to you after testing.